# how to create new column with random float values in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried using this code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand,when
df1 = df.withColumn('isVal', when(rand()0.5,1).otherwise(0.6))
```

but this code only  generate integer number i want to generate number bwtween 1.5 to 2.5 how can i do this in pyspark?

Comment: This code doesn't run. Do you want to generate floating point values between 1.5 and 2.5? Then what is this 0.5 and 0.6?

Comment: 0.5 and 0.6 is just example but actually i want to generate  between 1.5 to 2.5 using pyspark

Comment: I have added an answer after you clarified. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Some mathematics - `1.5+rand()` will be between `[1.5,2.5]` because `maximum` value of `rand()` can be `1`, so `1.5+1=2.5` and `minimum` is `0`, so `1.5+0=1.5`

```
df = df.withColumn('isVal', 1.5+rand())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
df1 = df.withColumn('isVal', 1.5+rand())
```

Comment: "I want to generate number bwtween 1.5 to 2.5 how can i do this in pyspark?"
I think it answers the question.